# Python: Sql result with Unix time into seconds

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

I have following query,

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(rc_timestamp) AS LAG_TIME FROM recentchanges ORDER BY rc_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

In my python code I am trying to get it to convert into seconds, but what I am currently getting is following:

```
{'LAG_TIME': 32L}
```

I tried with utf but results is same.

```
getLagTime = ur"""SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(rc_timestamp) AS LAG_TIME FROM recentchanges ORDER BY rc_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"""
cursor.execute(getLagTime)
lagTime = cursor.fetchall()
for time in lagTime:
    print time
    print unicode(time['LAG_TIME'], 'utf-8', error='strict')
```

Comment: Add your python code to the question.

Comment: I updated the code, its a tiny fraction of a very lengthy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you already have the answer: 32 seconds. Don't get confused by the "L". It tells you, that this is a long value, and not an int.